# MapView - Android

Tags: android, google-maps, nullpointerexception, google-play-services, google-maps-android-api-2

Hello I'm trying to add **MapView** to **LinearLayout** this is my code:

```
GoogleMap mMap = mMapView.getMap();
if (mMap != null) {
    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(-33.87365, 151.20689), 10);
    if (cameraUpdate != null)
        mMap.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);
    setUpMap(mMap);
}
```

[documantation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/CameraUpdateFactory)  says; Wait for a `GoogleMap` to become available from a `MapFragment` or `MapView` that you have added to your application. You can verify that the `GoogleMap` is available by calling the `getMap()` method and checking that the returned object is not null.

But i still get

> java.lang.NullPointerException: CameraUpdateFactory is not initialized.

is there any way to check cameraUpdateFactory is ready?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can force an initialization with the following code

```
    try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(context);
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException impossible) {
        /* Impossible */
    }
```

Place this snippet in your `onCreate` method to the top and it should work.

Comment: I have this snippet in my Fragment's onAttach(), but I still see the question's exception in the wild (I can't reproduce it, myself). Unfortunately, I don't know whether the 'impossible' exception happened, or whether getMap() returned null.